# Unable to Dockerize Vite React-Typescript Project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, docker, vite

I am trying to dockerize a Vite React-Typescript boilerplate setup, but I unable to connect to the container.

Installed vite-react-typescript boilerplate:

`npm init vite@latest vite-docker-demo -- --template react-ts`

**Dockerfile**

```
# Declare the base image
FROM node:lts-alpine3.14
# Build step
# 1. copy package.json and package-lock.json to /app dir
RUN mkdir /app
COPY package*.json /app
# 2. Change working directory to newly created app dir
WORKDIR /app
# 3 . Install dependencies
RUN npm ci
# 4. Copy the source code to /app dir
COPY . .
# 5. Expose port 3000 on the container
EXPOSE 3000
# 6. Run the app
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Command to run docker container in detached mode and open local dev port 3000 on host:
`docker run -d -p 3000:3000 vite`

The vite instance seems to be running just fine within the container (docker logs output):

```
> vite-docker@0.0.0 dev /app
> vite

Pre-bundling dependencies:
  react
  react-dom
(this will be run only when your dependencies or config have changed)

  vite v2.4.4 dev server running at:

  > Local: http://localhost:3000/
  > Network: use `--host` to expose

  ready in 244ms.
```

However, when I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/` within Chrome. I see an error indicating `The connection was reset`.

Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to configure `host` to something other than `localhost`.

Within `vite.config.ts`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3000,
  },
  plugins: [reactRefresh()],
})
```

Resolves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

in package.json use script

```
"dev": "vite --host"
```

example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
```

or run with `vite --host`

Answer (score 0):

To use hot reload, so the changes actually get reflected:

```
export default (conf: any) => {
  return defineConfig({
    server: {
      host: "0.0.0.0",
      hmr: {
        clientPort: ENV_VARIABLES.OUTER_PORT_FRONTEND,
      },
      port: ENV_VARIABLES.INNER_PORT_FRONTEND_DEV, 
      watch: {
        usePolling: true,
      },
    },
  });
};
```