# Vite + React Docker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, vite

I'm trying to run my vite+react app using the docker container, the code is running fine but unfortunately, it's not opening in localhost 3000

**DockerFile**

```
FROM node:18-alpine

EXPOSE 3000

WORKDIR /react-vite-app

COPY package.json .

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

CMD [ "yarn","build"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    reactapp:
      build: ./dir
      container_name: react_vite_app
      ports:
        - '3000:3000'
```

Is something missing, If something is wrong please help me to fix this

Comment: What URL are you trying to connect to and what error do you get?  How does the application set up its network listener; can you [edit] the question to include the required application code as well?  (Wild guess: it's only listening on the 127.0.0.1 container-private localhost interface, and you need to set it to listen to 0.0.0.0 instead.)

Comment: vite listens on localhost:5173 by default. You may also need the `--host` option to make it listen to connections outside of localhost if you run it in a docker.

Comment: Exact same issue, I find the solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68595302/16795034

Answer (score 7):

Set port in vite config to 3000

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3000,
  },
  plugins: [ your plugins here ],
})
```

Also run docker like this

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /react-vite-app

EXPOSE 3000

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install --silent

COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same issue from the same config, I found the solution here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68595302/16795034

Answer (score 0):

my settings

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN npm install serve -g

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite -p 3000",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "serve": "serve -s dist -p 3000"
  },
  "dependencies": {
   ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not use the preview command in production because apparently it is not recommended, it is only used to have a preview.

I better recommend using the serve package created by vercel.

Comment: Is `serve` a NPM dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set `host` in your `vite.config.js` file because you might encounter connection reset problem when you open your browser

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3000,
  },
  preview: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 8000,
  },
})
```

Dev : `npm run dev`, listening port : 3000

Prod : `npm run build` `npm run preview`, listening port : 8000