# Vite+React+Docker: not working in container

Tags: reactjs, docker, vite

I'm writing a standard react app using vite and yarn. I'm new to vite...

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "bpm",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "vite": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

vite.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  server: {host:'0.0.0.0', port:8080},
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

When I run it directly in wsl (ubuntu), using `yarn dev` it works fine. I can point my browser at `http://localhost:8080` and my app runs with no problems.

I also have this basic dockerfile which I build in the normal way:

```
from node:alpine3.15
workdir /app
copy package.json /app/package.json
run yarn
copy src /app/src
copy public /app/public
copy vite.config.js /app/
cmd ["yarn", "dev", "--debug"]
```

But, when I run this in wsl:

```bash
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 bpm
```

The app no longer works.

What do I mean by 'no longer works'? Well, that's where it gets interesting. When the app starts the debugging output shows that vite has resolved all of its dependencies, so vite appears to be working, it reports no errors on stdout, and reports its port bindings. But, when I access the app root: `http://localhost:8080` I get a 404.

I can access the files in the app if I enter their URI's: `curl http://localhost:8080/src/main.jsx` returns the appropriate source-code. So, this isn't a docker networking problem.

If I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/index.html` then that page loads and the network tab shows no problems, but the console reports an error:

```
@vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble. Something is wrong. See https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/pull/11#discussion_r430879201
    at Toolbar.jsx:6:11
```

Where `Toolbar.jsx` is on of my component files.

Just in case, I read the docs and tried adding:

```bash
origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
```

To the vite server config and it hasn't helped (surprisingly).

There seem to be some other questions on this topic ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73623891/vite-react-docker) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68595151/unable-to-dockerize-vite-react-typescript-project/68595302#68595302)), but those questions and answers don't seem to cover the actual behaviour I'm seeing, though I have read them and applied their solutions they don't help.

I've also tried different base containers for node, and different versions of node. It doesn't seem to make any difference.

I've been banging my head against this all evening but it's getting annoying now. Any insights would be appreciated.

## Note

I can `vite build` the app and serve it in nginx, and it works, but that really doesn't help during development.

Comment: Please upload to github a minimal working solution with dockerfile, codes etc that can reproduce the same error you are seeing with your actual project.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I reproduced the same error. You have to set **host to true** in your vite config and you have to copy all files in your dockerfile, those inside and outside src folder, index.html is outside your src folder and you are not copying it

**Compared to CRA using vite your index.html have to be on your root directory in dev mode. If you want to serve it from public directory you have to add some middleware for that, but it's  more like a workaround, I don't advice you doing this since the public directory is for assets like robots.txt file ...**

https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory

**-vite config file**

```
export default defineConfig({
 plugins: [react()],
 server: {
  watch: {
   usePolling: true,
  },
  host: true, // Here
  strictPort: true,
  port: 8080, 
}
```

**-Dockerfile file**

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN yarn
# copy all files
COPY . .
cmd ["yarn", "dev", "--debug"]
```

And if you copy everything (COPY . .) Don't forget to add a .dockerignore file

```
.git
.vscode
.dockerignore
.gitignore
.env
config
build
node_modules
docker-compose.yaml
Dockerfile
README.md
```

Try to build your image again and run and let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: Thanks, but that produced exactly the same results as my original attempt at this. To bypass any potential networking problems, I've exec'd into the container and curl'd `http://localhost:8080` (using your config as posted here) and I get a 404.

Comment: I think i know your problem, you are missing some files that you didn't move inside your container like configs one and the index it self, i will post a proper dockerfile for you

Comment: Wow. @FatehMohamed - I was about to write your comment off, because I already have the config file inside my container. However, I did pay attention and I noticed that I was missing the base index.html file. So, you were write, I was missing a file. All this time, something so simple! I have the index.html file in my project root and I hadn't even noticed it. I have a copy in my `public` folder and another in my `src` (probably both redundant). If you write this up as an answer I'll give you the bounty if you like.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it, i added some clarifications on the answer

Comment: You were using "Create react app"  before? because the file structure is not that same as vite, for vite index.html has to be in root directory and if you use CRA it has to be in public one

Comment: Ah! That's interesting, thanks. I didn't realise that. I had started with CRA (as I usually do), and only later became aware of vite and patched it into my project. I really like it, despite how confusing it can be.

Comment: thanks again. One thing, it might be worth mentioning in your answer that the `COPY . .` line is only sensible if you have a `.dockerignore` file that excludes the files you don't want in the image. Or, change it to copy only the files you want (which is my preferred approach)(although I do use the `.dockerignore` to save having to copy my `node_modules` folder into the docker staging area, which can take a long time for a complex project). In fact, `COPY . .` is potentially dangerous so we (the companies I work for) ban it outright and insist on a targetted copy.

Comment: That's a good strategy and more safe yes

Comment: "your index.html have to be on your root directory in dev mode" that saved me, thanks !
An error should be raised or something x)