# I'm able to build a docker image and start a container from it, however the localhost port either refuses to connect or doesn't send data

Tags: docker, dockerfile, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm trying to build a container for an app I'm building using docker. The app works locally before containerization. After building a dockerfile I was able to successfully create an image and start a container from that. However when i go to localhost:5173 (default port from vite) nothing shows even though i bind that port to the exposed port within my dockerfile. I'm not getting any errors via docker when creating the image or container to look into.

### Below is the current code for my dockerfile

```
FROM node:18.14

WORKDIR /user/src/app/visualizer

COPY . /user/src/app/

COPY package*.json /user/src/app/visualizer

RUN npm ci

EXPOSE 4000

ENTRYPOINT npm run dev
```

### And this is the code for my package.json

```
{
    "name": "",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "test": "npm run test:integration && npm run test:unit",
        "lint": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --check . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --write .",
        "test:integration": "playwright test",
        "test:unit": "vitest"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@playwright/test": "^1.28.1",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^2.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.20.4",
        
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "daisyui": "^3.2.1",
        "eslint": "^8.28.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.30.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.24",
        "postcss-load-config": "^4.0.1",
        "prettier": "^2.8.0",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.10.1",
        "svelte": "^4.0.0",
        "svelte-check": "^3.4.3",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
        "vite": "^4.3.6",
        "vitest": "^0.32.2"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "pocketbase": "^0.15.0-rc"
    }
}
```

### And below is the file structure at the moment

Root
|
|-apps (Dockerfile lives here)
| |
| |-backend
| |-visualizer
| | |
| | |-.sveltekit
| | |-src
| | |-static
| | |-tests

I've tried editing the src locations in the dockerfile for some of the files thinking that I might have the paths down incorrectly. I also tried to RUN npm run build within the image but that had it building the image for 5+ minutes. I hit many errors on initial image building and the code above is what i have that actually allows the image to be built out.Those errors i had were mentioning vite and sveltekit but i think the npm ci covered those. I tried starting the container with docker run -d -p 5173:4000  and checked both localhost ports in chrome with nothing rendering on the screen. Docker ps confirms that I've got a container up and running. My understanding is that if i go to localhost:5173 it should connect to the container at 4000 and show my app.

Comment: Does [running a vite dev server inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012970/running-a-vite-dev-server-inside-a-docker-container) answer your question?

Comment: does this help ? [vitereactdocker-not-working-in-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74229258/vitereactdocker-not-working-in-container)